# C# sqlConnection authentication exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Working on writing a C# application which will query a SQL Server 2008 R2 database instance. My code (with mods to the connection string) is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MosaiqToCTWorklist
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Establish a connection string
        string connectionString = "Data Source=IPADDRESS;Password=PASSWORD;User ID=USERID;Initial Catalog=dbName";
        SqlConnection dbConnection;  

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            Test();        
        }

        private void Test()
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time connecting to a database and utilized the Project > Add new data source wizard to generate the connection string defined in `connectionString`. The `Test()` method was just for debugging purposes.

I'm getting the following InnerException:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

I'm at a level I do not understand why I can connect to this database using the source wizard but it fails when I write out the code. I was not able to find anything this specific and am hopeful for some additional insight as to what Visual Studio 2012 is doing behind the scenes. Thank you.

[image: Specific Error Message]

Comment: Do you have Sql Service Management Studio?  If so open it up and try to connect with the same creds.

Comment: Make sure there are no semi-colons or unescaped backslashes in your password, or the password you're sending to SQL Server will not be what you think you're sending.

Comment: @kmacdonald: I did verify creds prior to and they were accepted.

Comment: @dodexahedron: The password is clean between the equals and the ending semicolon.

Comment: I am open to negative ratings and am striving to improve questions I post, however I would ask that objective comments be left indicating the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are having is not related to your code, it is caused from the parameters you have in the connection string. It cannot find the Server.

To connect to SQL Server sometimes is not enough to specify the IP address or server name only, you need to specify the port if it is not the default one (usually 1433) and the instance name. For example, using SQL Server Express by default it creates the instance named "SQLEXPRESS", so to be able to connect to it you need to include it in the server name/IP address:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=IpAddress\InstanceName,Port; Password=PWD; User ID=USERID; Initial Catalog=dbName";
```

Take a look here: [SQL Server 2008 ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) it is all explained there. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the link, it was actually what I had used to help me round one. Instance name should be taken care of Initial Catalog=dbName.

Comment: You need to specify the Instance Name whether you specify the database or not (if you are not using the default one). You can have multiple instances of SQL Server running in the same computer and they can use the same database names.

[Take a look at this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0628296e-939a-4700-b498-1c3c9ce90597/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlsecurity)

Comment: I did end up going back and adding in the instance utilizing "\\" between the IP address and the instance name. Same issue however. Thank you though, needed regardless.

Comment: [This](http://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/) site indicates that escape characters are not supported. I changed my connection string from a '\\' to an @ at the beginning of the string. Still no luck, posted a photo of the exactly error.

Comment: Any chance you can share your current connection string? (just remove user and pwd). There should not be a problem using the @ or the "\\" in the string, both works the same.

Comment: My current connection string is as follows: 'string connectionString = @"Data Source=11.111.11.111\Instance;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=false;Trusted_Connection=false;User ID=User;Password=User";'

Comment: So when I stepped back through the debugger I took a closer look at the connection string and noticed that ' Data Source=11.11.11.111\\Instance ' instead of having a single ' \ '. I'm using the ' @ ' in front of the string. Any reason why this is occurring? I cleaned the solution and rebuilt, no success. I bet a buck that's the issue.

Comment: Well... if you use the @ remove the second \, otherwise use \\. It's weird that behaviour. I'm sorry I'm out of ideas. Any chance you can try to connect using SQL Management Studio, so you can see the connection parameters more clearly? Or even check if you have TCP connections enable for SQL Server and that you are using the right TCP port...

Comment: I have to apologies the double "\\" is a function of the debugger and not of what the string actually represents. I printed the connection String out to message box and it looks fine. Learned something new : )

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DBSource;Password=Password;User ID=UserName;Initial Catalog=DBName";`

Try connection string as mention above.
Not require to provide port information to connect in.

Comment: Just want to be sure that I do not need to have credentials to log onto the server in which this db instance is correct? the sqlConnection and the connectionString should be just a direct connect to the db in question should it not? The credentials to access the db and server are different.